# how to put shortcode to the top of the page - theme 2014

Tags: php, apache, linux

experts

running a wp 4.6,1 -. with a specail theme - called 2014 extended!

question; 
can i put this to the top of the page:

```
[su_tabs] [su_tab title="Technische Literatur" anchor="First"][amazon asin=0893817449,0500410607,050054199X,0500286426,0893818755,050054333X,0500543178,0945506562&amp;template=slider] [/su_tab]
  [su_tab title=" Kochbücher " anchor="Second"][amazon asin=0893817449,0500410607,050054199X,0500286426,0893818755,050054333X,0500543178,0945506562&amp;template=slider] [/su_tab]
  [su_tab title="Biographien" anchor="Third"] [amazon asin=0893817449,0500410607,050054199X,0500286426,0893818755,050054333X,0500543178,0945506562&amp;template=slider] [/su_tab][/su_tabs]
```

i want to put it a bit more to the top of the page....

at the moment it is arranged in the first article / posting....

love to hear from you

Comment: May you please [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/243015/edit) your question and elaborate more? What do you mean by "top of the page"?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to edit the header.php of your theme and use the Wordpress function [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

```
$myShortCode = "[your_short_code]"; 
do_shortcode($myShortCode);
```

This will output the content generated by your shortcode wherever you want.